# JWPlayer access files on DFS Share

Tags: asp.net, jwplayer

I have an ASP.NET (.Net 3.5) website and I want to use JWPlayer 6.10.  I can get the player to display but it won't play files.  I'm setting the filename in the C# codebehind and that seems to be working fine.  However, it seems that the JWPlayer can't connect and read the mp3 file from the DFS share location.  I've tried several values for filename such as 'file://xyz/files/adf/1234.mp3', 'file:///\xyz\files/ad/1234.mp3', '//xyz/files/adf/1234.mp3', etc. but I can't seem to find a format that works.  What is the correct format for JWPlayer to access a file on DFS?

```
 <head>  
 <script src="JWPlayer-6.10/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>jwplayer.key = "ABC123==";</script>
 <script src="JWPlayer-6.10/jwplayer.html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
 </head>

 <body>
 jwplayer('jw6player').setup({
   "flashplayer": "JWPlayer-6.10/jwplayer.flash.swf",
   "file": '<%=filename %>',
   "type": "mp3",
   "id": "jwPlayer6",
   "width": 640,
   "height": 30
  });

  </body>
```

Comment: JW Player is executing client-side, so the path to the file must either be relative to the calling page, or absolute, with an http: protocol.

Comment: A couple of other notes... First, do not explicity load jwplayer.html5.js or jwplayer.flash.swf. Just co-locate those files with jwplayer.js, which will call them if it needs to. Calling them explicitly can cause problems. Second, the "type" attribute should be used only within a playlist. Third, there's no need for the "type" attribute if the file extension is MP3 (or MP4, etc.) - it's only needed where the file type is ambiguous. Fourth, there is no "id" attribute. (cont...)

Comment: Finally, you're trying to execute jwplayer.setup(), but you haven't created a div with a matching ID. A simple example: http://misterneutron.com/JW6audio/. See the configuration guide - you can't just wing it: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406724-aac-or-mp3-audio-embed

Comment: It also looks like the setup isn't in script tags.